# WebRTC + nodejs/socketio no audio

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc

Some days working on this, and no luck, I'm just trying to get the basic example working of only audio, but no audio on index1.html, everything works, no issues, connection established, offer/answer exchanged, icecandidate also exchanged, this is not working on both chrome or firefox.

I don't know whats wrong, I'm just exactly copying https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/audio/ just splitting it out into 2 files, I dont get it, also I see a lot of people saying that the issue is wit stun/ice servers, actually the examples work without them so I guess I dont need them.

The setup:
index.html, the one who will initiate the call and capture its audio.
index1.html, will receive the call and play the audio.

PD: the code isn't clean or anything, just testing stuff.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hello World! Site Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <button id="call">CALL</button>

  </body>
  <script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
  <script>
var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
//const { RTCPeerConnection, RTCSessionDescription } = window;

let callButton = document.getElementById("call");
let peerConnection;
socket.on('sendICe_to_0', data => {
  console.log("received ice candidate", data);
  peerConnection.addIceCandidate(data.candidate);
});

callButton.onclick = e => {
  peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
  peerConnection.onicecandidate = e => {
    console.log("send ice to 1", e);
    socket.emit('sendICe_to_1', e);
  }

    navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: false
    })
    .then(gotStream)
    .catch(e => {
      alert(`getUserMedia() error: ${e.name}`);
    });
};


async function gotStream(stream) {
  console.log("capturing audio");
  stream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream));

  let offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
  await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
  console.log("sending offer", offer);
  socket.emit('offer_to_1', offer);

  /*peerConnection.createOffer()
      .then(data => {
        console.log("creating offer", data);
          peerConnection.setLocalDescription(data)
          .then(data => {
              console.log("sending offer", data);
              socket.emit('offer_to_1', data);
          });

      });*/

}

socket.on('send_asnwer_0', data => {
    console.log("received anser", data);
    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(data);
});

  </script>
</html>
```

**index1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hello World! Site Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <audio id="audio" autoplay controls></audio>

  </body>
  <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

  <script>
    // https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/470
var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
let peerConnection;

socket.on('sendICe_to_1', data => {
  console.log("Received ice candidate", data);

  peerConnection.onicecandidate = e => {
  console.log("Sending ice candidate", e)

    socket.emit('sendICe_to_0', e);
  };

  peerConnection.addIceCandidate(data.candidate);

  peerConnection.ontrack = e => {
    console.log("Adding remote stream");
    let audio = document.querySelector('audio#audio');
    if (audio.srcObject !== e.streams[0]) {
        audio.srcObject = e.streams[0];
        console.log('Received/Configured remote stream');
    }
  };


});

async function offerTo1(data) {
  peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
  console.log("Received offer from 0", data)
  await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(data)
  let answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
  await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
  console.log("sending answer", answer);
  socket.emit('send_asnwer_0', answer);
}

socket.on('offer_to_1',  data => {
    offerTo1(data);
});

</script>
</html>
```

NodeJs server

```
const io = require('socket.io')();
io.origins('*:*');
io.listen(3000);

let connectedSockets = [];

/*io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    connectedSockets.push(socket);
    console.log("Client connected!");
    socket.on('sendAudio', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        connectedSockets[1].emit("receiveAudio", data)
    })
});*/

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    connectedSockets.push(socket);
    console.log("Client connected!");

    socket.on("offer_to_1", (data) => {
        console.log("offer_to_1")
        connectedSockets[1].emit("offer_to_1", data);
    });

    socket.on('send_asnwer_0', data => {
        console.log("send_asnwer_0")

        connectedSockets[0].emit("send_asnwer_0", data);
    });



    socket.on("sendICe_to_1", (data) => {
        console.log("sendICe_to_1")

        connectedSockets[1].emit("sendICe_to_1", data);
    });

    socket.on("sendICe_to_0", (data) => {
        console.log("sendICe_to_0")

        connectedSockets[0].emit("sendICe_to_0", data);
    });


});
```

Comment: You never put the audio anywhere, you can read the [docs](https://webrtc.org/getting-started/remote-streams)

Comment: Hello @DirkV thanks for the answer, actually I put it in index1.html in peerConnection.ontrack, is that not enough or do I need something more?  I also checked your doc and I think im doing that at index.html function gotStream that is being used as callback for navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Comment: How have you implemented ontrack?

Comment: Hello, yes in index1.html peerConnection.ontrack , What I dont have is MediaStream.

Comment: mediastream is a universally available in the browser